# .net Core console app on Ubuntu 20.10 on raspberry pi 4 give No such file or directory when trying to execute the program

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, raspberry-pi, asp.net-core-3.1, raspberry-pi4

I've published my Hello World console app to my raspberry PI 4 running Ubuntu 20.10 using the publish function in VS2019 and copied it to my PI using scp.

When I try to start the program (i've chmod it to executable) I get error:

> bash: ./AppName: No such file or directory

The steps to create my app:

- I've create a Hello World C# .NET Core console application in Visual Studio 2019 community edition
- I published it (right click on project name in the solution explorer)

  - Target: folder
  - Specific target: folder
- Profile settings

  - Configuration: Debug | Any CPU
  - target framework: netcoreapp3.1
  - Deployment mode: Self-contained
  - Target runtime: Linux-arm
  - Produce single file: checked
- copied the files in the publish folder using scp * username@10.10.2.22:/home/username/Downloads/core
- chmod 777 AppName
- ./AppName

I get the error:

> bash: ./AppName: No such file or directory

I must be overlooking something simple, but I cannot find it.

How to run my Hello World C# .NET Core console app on my Raspberry PI4 running on Ubuntu 20.10?

Comment: Basically looks good and is the normal way of doing this. What does `ls` say?

Comment: @PMF It just says: "bash: ./AppName: No such file or directory". Nothing more, nothing less. I've installed Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (Buster) and that works fine. I wonder if it has something to do with Ubuntu being 64 bit.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. There's something wrong with the file structure. After the Chmod command, can you check the directory contents? The AppName file should show up in green and have "-rwxrwxrwx" access permissions.

Comment: @PMF AppName is shown in green and has -rwxrwxrwx permissions.

Comment: If I xxd into AppName there is a path /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 that seems to be missing. I've found that file, copied it to /lib, now it is missing some other file (libdl.so.2). So I think I'm missing some kind of library, but I'm not sure how to install it on a proper way (read: not copy manually)

Comment: That shouldn't normally happen for self-contained applications. Maybe there's a 64 bit issue anyway. The target framework "linux-arm" is 32 bit only, I think. Try building for "portable" instead (and eventually try framework-dependent as well, with the correct framework installed)

Answer (score 2):

This ancient question has no answer, but just in case you're getting here from a search engine, the [answer is here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101429/no-such-file-or-directory-when-executing-a-cross-compiled-program-on-a-raspber).

> How to identify the problem?

```
file cross_compiled_executable
```

Contains something like:

```
interpreter /lib/ld-uClibc.so.0
```

and the problem is that that file does not exist on the target.

This means that you probably built it for the wrong architecture (32 vs 64 bit)

I changed linux-arm to **linux-arm64**

```
dotnet build -c Release -r linux-arm
```

to

```
dotnet build -c Release -r linux-arm64
```

and everything is working again.